# TFS checkin error VS2013 - The process cannot access the file

Tags: tfs

Consistently getting a checkin error via VS2013 for a MVC project. Have been spending quite some time but still dont get whats happening.

The project is cleaned. Checked that Application Experience is set to automatic. I am running on Windows 7

Any help ?

Comment: What is the error? If you want help, you should provide as much detail as possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is a file in your solution that does not exist on disk. Maybe it was deleted manually. If you know the file you can go looking for where it is referenced in your project hierarchy. It should be listed with a yellow triangle.

Either remove it or replace it.

If you don't have a local copy but it is still on the server you can find it in the Sourfe Explorer and do a Get Specific | Latest to recreate it.